# Display full path of current notebook on title bar?

Tags: notebooks, interface

Is there a setting in Mathematica notebook interface to get the title bar to display the full path to the current notebook?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a setting in the Global Preferences:  Notebook Options | Window Properties | WindowTitle | "FullFileName"

[image]

Comment: In Mathematica V12.3, we can only set it for the current notebook, but fail to set for global preference. How to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: @likehust - Appears to have stopped working some time after v12.0 Works in 12.0; doesn't in 12.1.1 (I don't have access to 12.1.0) Suggest you submit "Product Feedback" to Wolfram Tech Support

Answer (score 4):

You could also use:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowTitle -> "FullFileName"]
```